# Python AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save' when trying to save a cropped image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a portion of an image blurred.  Eventually I want to blur faces, but I cannot get just a portion to blur.  I am attempting to crop a portion of an image then paste it back onto the original image.  I am able to crop it on, but when I go to save the image with the cropped region pasted on, I receive an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'"

Here is the code I am using:

```
import Image, ImageFilter

picture = Image.open("picture1.jpg")

#finds width and height of picture
width, height = picture.size

#crops the picture
box = (20, 20, width/2, height/2)
ic = picture.crop(box)

#blurs the cropped part of the picture
ic = ic.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=20))

#pastes the image back    
blurredPic = picture.paste(ic, box)

#saves the new image and the cropped image
blurredPic.save("BlurredPic.jpg")
ic.save("cropPic.jpg")
```

I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

`picture.paste(ic, box)` mutates `picture` in-place and returns `None`.

ie.

```
#blurs the cropped part of the picture
ic = ic.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=20))

#pastes the image back    
picture.paste(ic, box)

#saves the new image and the cropped image
picture.save("BlurredPic.jpg")
ic.save("cropPic.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the library you're using, but I found some examples for the Image library here: http://www.riisen.dk/dop/pil.html.  Looking at the Transpose example, it looks like the paste function is in place.

When you call picture.paste(ic, box), what you are doing is updating picture, and not returning anything.  As a result, blurredPic has the value of None, which naturally doesn't have the attribute "save".

I would change the last 3 lines to be this:

```
picture.paste(ic, box)

#saves the new image and the cropped image
picture.save("BlurredPic.jpg")
ic.save("cropPic.jpg")
```

If that's not the correct library, or that doesn't solve your problem, let me know.